# how to add multiple fileds of the same name with different data

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

so what i am doing is sending this data to the the firebase firestore here's my code its working fine,

```
final data = {
  "sent_requests" : {
    "sender"   :  "${loggedInUser.uid}",
    "receiver" :  args.uid,
    "details"  :  {
    "date"              :  detail_class.datetime, 
    "total_dishes"      :  detail_class.total_dishes,                     
    "total_people"      :  detail_class.total_people,
    "meals"             :  detail_class.meals, 
    "location"          :  detail_class.location,
     }  
  }
};

dynamic db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
db.collection("users").doc("${loggedInUser.uid}").set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

[image: firestore result]

This result is fine, but this code just overwrites the previous request. I instead want to add more requests in it,
when the sender and receiver are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field names are unique in Firestore, so you can't have (for example) two `receiver` fields.

What you **can** have is a single field that is an array of values. I'd typically call that `receivers` (plural) to indicate that it's a multi-value field, and you'd write that from your code with:

```
final data = {
  "sent_requests" : {
    ...
    "receivers" :  [args.uid],
    ...
  }  
};
```

This **sets** the `receivers` field to an array with just the value or `args.uid`. If you want to merge the `args.uid` with any existing values in the database already, you can use an [`array-union` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
final data = {
  "sent_requests" : {
    ...
    "receivers" :  FieldValue.arrayUnion([args.uid]),
    ...
  }  
};
```

Now the `args.uid` value will be added to the `receivers` array, unless it's already in there.